# SyntaxError: Failed to load plugin '@next/next' declared in '.eslintrc.json » eslint-config-next/core-web-vitals

Tags: next.js

I'm getting this error on a fresh installation of Next.js with

```
npx create-next-app@latest
```

which installs `next 14.1.0`

Node version 18.19.1

Searching around this seems to be common issue with different causes, but the solutions I've found are outdated (update `eslint-config-next` to 12 while I've v14 installed, or update Node to 18)